# I want to split an array into subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert array into multiple arrays.Here is my output.please help

```
 Array ( [0] => a,b,cc,dd);
    Array ( [0] => 1,b,cc,4);
    Array ( [0] => tt,b,uc,dp);
    Array ( [0] => 4a,b,cc4,ddu);
```

i want an o/p like this:i want to split this array into multiple array for fetching each data.

```
Array ( [1] =>a);
Array ( [2] =>b);
Array ( [3] =>cc);
Array ( [4] =>dd);
Array ( [5] =>1);
Array ( [6] =>b);......
```

..............

Comment: What you have tried? Post your attempts too? Is this a single array or four different arrays

Comment: when i convert my csv data into array.i got an output like this,which contains these 4 arrays.containg the data.

Comment: it is very difficult to fetch data because all datas are in 4 arrays with same name,so i want to split it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try using `array_column`, `array_walk`, and `call_user_func_array`

```
$arr = [Array ( 0 => 'a,b,cc,dd'),
    Array ( 0 => '1,b,cc,4'),
    Array ( 0 => 'tt,b,uc,dp'),
    Array ( 0 => '4a,b,cc4,ddu')];
$result = [];
$column = array_column($arr, 0);
array_walk($column,function($v, $k)use(&$result){
    $result[] = explode(",", $v);
});
$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $result);
```

Or simply use `array_walk_recursive` as suggested by [@Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123)

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$result) {
    $result = array_merge($result, explode(",", $v));
});
```

Comment: And if you want to save a few characters: `array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$result){
  $result = array_merge($result, explode(",", $v));
 });`

Comment: Good One @Rizier123 Why don't you post it as an answer

Comment: You already posted one :) And for my liking OP didn't showed enough effort where I say I would answer the question.

Comment: Do you think I should remove this answer. @Rizier123 and let the question be closed

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Nah, you already posted the answer and Stack Overflow doesn't want to lose good answers :) Also this might help others SO visitors, so I would definitely keep it.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Also you still have a little error in your code (variables should only be passed by reference), if you want to apply this edit: http://pastebin.com/hP8NgTzZ or change it as you want it.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for refering  I've updated the answer